# ML Kit Barcode Detection - isOperational() is always false - No acceptable module found

Tags: android, barcode, firebase-mlkit

I'm working on an android app using ML Kit Barcode Detection, but I'm not able to make it work on the target device.

when calling isOperational() on the detector it always returns false, indicating the required dependencies haven't been downloaded to the device. As per the tutorial on barcode detection:

"It's possible that the first time our barcode detector runs, Google Play Services won't be ready to process barcodes yet. So we need to check if our detector is operational before we use it. If it isn't, we may have to wait for a download to complete, or let our users know that they need to find an internet connection or clear some space on their device."

However, after several runs, it still isn't working.

Digging into the logs I found this:
"Error loading module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode optional module true: gg: No acceptable module found. The local version is 0 and the remote version is 0."

I'm running on a Galaxy Tab A (2019) with android 9, and everything (including google play services) up to date. It's a brand new tablet with 21GB free space.

Running the same app on a Galaxy s20, the issue doesn't exist. It ran on the first try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this, I think I may have just been going off an old version of the api. So I started over using the firebase assistant within android studio and used that barcode reader.